# i having a bug in my prompt() method , intead of getting a string get a null value

Tags: javascript, prompt

```
var message = "";
var student;

function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

function getStudentReport(student) {
  let report = "<h2>Student: " + student.name + "</h2>";
  report += "<p>Track: " + student.track + "</p>";
  report += "<p>Points: " + student.points + "</p>";
  report += "<p>Achievements: " + student.achievements + "</p>";
  return report;
}

while (true) {
  var search = prompt('Search student record: type a name [Jody
] (or type "quit" to end)');
  if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === "quit") {
    break;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.name === search) {
      message = getStudentReport(student);
      print(message);
    }
  }
}
```

I am having the following problem, I am trying to gather user information through `prompt()` as I know so far `prompt()` by default it will always return a string, but in this case, it is returning `null` as output.

[If you would like to see the whole process follow this link](https://github.com/AlejandroBryan/object)

Comment: in which cases return null?  the normal case is "If the user clicks the Cancel button, this function returns null." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: but if the user type ok and the input is empty should break as well. if  user the type **quit **  my return is quit

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove line break. Check out the snippet bellow.

```js
var message = "";
var students = [{
  name: 'Jody',
  track: 2,
  points: 80,
  achievements: 'none'
}];

function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

function getStudentReport(student) {
  let report = "<h2>Student: " + student.name + "</h2>";
  report += "<p>Track: " + student.track + "</p>";
  report += "<p>Points: " + student.points + "</p>";
  report += "<p>Achievements: " + student.achievements + "</p>";
  return report;
}

while (true) {
  var search = prompt('Search student record: type a name [Jody] (or type "quit" to end)');

  if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === "quit") {
    break;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.name === search) {
      message = getStudentReport(student);
      print(message);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks you, but if I remove the brake line, my while  loop is running endlessly.

Comment: Line break, no the line with 'break;'.

Comment: Yeap, I meant you did broke string to multiple lines which causes syntax error. Nothing wrong with `break` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This two line:

```
var search = prompt('Search student record: type a name [Jody
 ] (or type "quit" to end)');
```

Join in one line.

```
var search = prompt('Search student record: type a name [Jody] (or type "quit" to end)');
```

The new line (line break) is broking your code.

Also you can use interpolation `` or \ at the end of first line to solve.